# Symfony2: inserting the one without the many of a one-to-many

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I continue to struggle with the Symfony/Doctrine approach to creating objects.  The present issue is how best to create an object on the one side of a one-to-many without creating an object on the many side.  The problem seems to stem from the many side being the owning side of the relationship and thus the determinant in whether an object is persisted.

Particulars: a client entity has a one-to-many relationship with member entity.  A client can be created by itself with

```
        $client  = new Client();
        $form = $this->createForm(new ClientType(), $client);
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($client);
            $em->flush();
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('client_show', array('id' => $client->getId())));
        }
```

and a client plus member or members, but not by itself with

```
$client  = new Client();
$member = new Member();
$client->addMember($member);
$form = $this->createForm(new ClientType(), $client);
$form->bind($request);
if ($form->isValid()) {
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $member->setClient($client);
    $em->persist($member);
    $em->flush();
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('client_show', array('id' => $client->getId())));
```

Client Entity:

```
class Client
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
    * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Member", mappedBy="client")
    * 
    */
    protected $members;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->members = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function getMembers()
    {
        return $this->members;
    }

    public function setMembers($members)
    {
        foreach ($members as $members)
        {
            $members->addClient($this);
        }
        $this->members = $members;
        return $this;
    }

    public function addMember(Member $member)
    {
        $this->members->add($member);
//        $member->setClient($this);
        return $this;
//        $this->members[] = $member;
    }

    public function removeMember(Member $member)
    {
        $this->members->removeElement($member);
        return $this;
    }
```

Member Entity:

```
class Member 
{

    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hid", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Client",inversedBy="members",cascade={"remove", "persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="clientId", referencedColumnName="id")
     * 
     */
     protected $client;

    public function setClient(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }
```

The above code throws an error if there is no member inserted.  Can a single bit of code work to add a client with or without a member be specified?

Comment: You need to post the relevant portions of your entity classes

Comment: @gview: Entities added in edit above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind takes the form data and writes it to the object, which then gets persisted.

You call:

```
$client->addMember($member);
```

before bind, essentially adding an empty object to your client, which does not appear to be what you want to do.  In fact, I expect the first code is exactly what you want, but your ClientType() is not proper.

I think you want something like:

```
<?php

namespace ormed\ormedBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class ClientType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('ClientField' // one of several, probably
                     ,null
                     ,array() // specify options
                     )
                ->add('member'
                     ,null
                     ,array()  // specify options
                     )
         ;
    }
}
```

adding

> $builder->('member' ...

will give the member selector to the form, and then your cascade persist should handle everything else.  You might want to specify member as an entity type and build the list via a query builder.

Comment: I'm sure my controller is screwed up.  It no longer works as I thought it had - I get a new entity error.  As for ClientType, member is defined as a collection field: `->add('members', 'collection', array(...`

Comment: Probably you want members to be an entity type instead of a collection.

Comment: the problem with making members an entity field is that the member must exist before the client in order for one to be chosen.  In this case, a member can only exist in relation to a client, so the client must exist first.  In other news, my quasi-random selection of code has stumbled on a working but possibly not Symfony-kosher solution.  See the answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

A createAction that appears to cover both situations: client with and client without a member.

```
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $client  = new Client();
    $form = $this->createForm(new ClientType(), $client);
    $form->bind($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $members = $client->getMembers();
        foreach ($members as $member)
        {
            $member->setClient($client);
            $em->persist($member);
        }
        $em->persist($client);
        $em->flush();
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('client_show', array('id' => $client->getId())));
    }        
    return array(
        'entity' => $client,
        'form'   => $form->createView(),
    );
```

Comment: well you got the half of my solution in there :P

Comment: @Lighthart - +1 for your contribution.  Thanks.